# How to use BEM stylus in React component?

Tags: reactjs, stylus, bem

For example, this is my BEM style stylus code:

```
.example 
  background yellow
.block
  background black
  &--modify1
    background red
  &--modify2
    background blue
```

If I want to use `.example` as classname of my component, I know this code:

```
<Component classname={style.example}>
```

But what if I want to use `.block--modify1` classname ? What should I do ?

Comment: how about you just leave BEM behind... https://maintainablecss.com/chapters/semantics/

Answer (score 0):

You may use some helpers like https://www.npmjs.com/package/bem-cn
or even try [bem-react-core](https://github.com/bem/bem-react-core) library which does this job automatically.